# Selecting a single record to display on a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with which a user can add friends. The ActionMethods in the controller are:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Add (string id = "")
{
    var model = _db.Users
            .OrderBy(r => r.UserName)
            .Where(r => r.Id == id).ToList()
            .Select(r => new FriendsList
            {
                RequesterID = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString(),
                RequesteeID = id,
                UserName = r.UserName,
                Status = "NewRequest",
                RequestDate = DateTime.Now,
                AcknowledgeDate = DateTime.Now
            });

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add (FriendsList friendslist)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _friend.Entry(friendslist).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        _friend.SaveChanges();
        return View(friendslist);
    }
}
```

And the view code looks like:

```
@model Max.Models.Social.FriendsList
<h2>Add</h2>
<div>
    @Model.id = @Model.id;
    @Model.RequesteeID = @Model.RequesteeID;
    @Model.Status = @Model.Status;
    @Model.UserName = @Model.UserName;
    @Model.RequesterID = @Model.RequesterID;

    <p>Add @Model.UserName ?<input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
</div>
```

I am not really sure how to get the data that was passed from the controller to post back to Add...but this is my best guess.

When all is said and done, this is the error I get back from the server:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Max.Models.ApplicationUser,Max.Models.Social.FriendsList]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Max.Models.Social.FriendsList'.

Why do I get that error?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the code sample, friendsList is a param and never used? Also, what is _friend?

Comment: Hi Chris, _friend is a class which is derived from DbContext, that "DBSets" the FriendsList Model. And yes, that is a typo on my part, the param is not used.

Comment: I doubt seriously that you were downvoted for "updating your question"; it is more likely that your changes drastically changed the meaning of the question.  However, taking the stance that "whatever I post I won't ever change" in response isn't going to be much better.  The point of the site it to cultivate high quality questions and answers, not bicker over spelling and punctuation.

Comment: I understand Claies, and I will keep that in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Add action method selects one user from the database into `model`, but that type is a `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator'2[Max.Models.ApplicationUser,Max.Models.Social.FriendsList]`, while your view accepts a `Max.Models.Social.FriendsList`.

So you need to select one record. You can do so using `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Add (string id = "")
{
    var model = _db.Users
            .OrderBy(r => r.UserName)
            .Where(r => r.Id == id).ToList()
            .Select(r => new FriendsList
            {
                RequesterID = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString(),
                RequesteeID = id,
                UserName = r.UserName,
                Status = "NewRequest",
                RequestDate = DateTime.Now,
                AcknowledgeDate = DateTime.Now
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (model == null)
    {
        // handle not found
    }

    return View(model);
}
```